# Ansible privilege escalation once per play

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible's [`become`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) functionality to run plays with a different user. Here is an example of my `site.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: webserver
  remote_user: ansible_user
  become: true
  roles:
    - role_a
    - role_b
```

This works as expected: Ansible uses `ansible_user` to connect to `webserver` and `sudo` afterwards to run the tasks in the defined roles as `root`. However it does run `sudo` once per task in each of the roles, which results in a significant overhead as executing `sudo` is rather slow.

How do I configure Ansible to apply it's `become`-configuration once per play instead of once per task?

Comment: Executing sudo should not be slow. This indicates a serious problem which you should find and fix ASAP.

Comment: Slow as in fraction of a second. That adds quite some delay I'd like to get rid of when executing hundreds of tasks. Nothing wrong with the sudo setup there.

Comment: I'm not sure you can, simply because each task is uploaded and executed separately. I'll be interested to see what anyone can come up with though.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Longer answer: use an other tool than ansible. Meanwhile, I use ansible daily to execute tens of thousands of tasks and the majority use become to run as root or even an other user. This has never been a bottleneck in the last 3 years. I can cite other issue that have been: high load on the vsphere infrastructure providing our vms, network constrictions, dns resolution time... I definitely think you are chasing the wrong windmill here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing privilege escalation only onces per play is possible by utilizing [Mitogen for Ansible](https://mitogen.networkgenomics.com/ansible_detailed.html).

From their documentation:

> One connection is used per target, in addition to one sudo invocation per user account. This is much better than SSH multiplexing combined with pipelining, as significant state can be maintained in RAM between steps, and system logs aren’t spammed with repeat authentication events.

Mitogen also provides additional performance benefits for running plays, such as reuse of Python interpreters.

It is however not compatible with all Ansible configurations as it replaces significant parts of Ansible! Their documentation lists [noteworthy differences to vanilla Ansible](https://mitogen.networkgenomics.com/ansible_detailed.html#noteworthy-differences), some of which might require changes to playbooks or might make using it completely unfeasible.

Comment: Mitogen is a fork of Ansible that significantly changes how connection plugins work, and has a subset of features.  https://mitogen.networkgenomics.com/ansible_detailed.html#noteworthy-differences    Personally, I don't consider a single digit number of seconds worth converting to Mitogen.

Comment: For my use case, together with all its other performance improvements, Mitogen cuts the time it takes to apply the tasks to one third of the time before. That's pretty impressive, especially as I didn't have to change anything in my playbooks to get it to work.You're right though, I should mention in the anwser that Mitogen is not compatible with all Ansible configurations.